# Talend Open Studio not opening after installation (JVM error)

Tags: java, talend, talend-mdm

I have installed Talend Open Studio (TOS_DI-20180927_1104-V7.1.1M4).

I am getting error -:

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library "......\jvm.dll"
```

a) Java & JRE is installed (1.8.0_181)
b) JAVA_HOME & Path of JDK bin is added in added in Environment variables.
c) System is 64 bit

I have also followed the suggestions on -:

https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/resolved-Talend-Integration-Studio-5-2-1-install-load-issue/td-p/75904

Still unable to resolve.
What setting can be done to resolve this?
Can I edit TOS_DI-win-x86_64.ini file to open the software.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the ini file is having the jvm.ddl from the JDK8 Path, if Not correct the path, and open the Talend IDE.

> Have a backup of .ini before editing,Incase you want to revert to previous setting.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by installing  -:
a) 64 bit JDK
b) 64 bit JRE
c) Setting  JDK bin PATH in Environment Variables
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
d) Setting  JAVA_HOME in Envrironment variables as 
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181
e) Setting JAVA_HOME\bin in PATH in Environment Variables
   %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Earlier installed JDK & JRE was of 32 bit and Talend of 64 bit.

No extra configuration required in .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded java 1.8, then added the \bin path to PATH variable list.   Then moved this new path to be above in the list any other java paths in the PATH variable list.   This fixed the issue for me.